# MonoMac NSTableView and NSTableViewDataSource Data Update

Tags: .net, monomac

Im trying to update the NSTableView when NSTableViewDataSource was updated.

NSTableViewDataSource uses an ArrayList & had Add() & Count() methods so my code would add data from Button Click action method.

Its similar to an example at:
http://www.netneurotic.de/Mono/MonoMac-NSTableView.html

I want to update the TableView manually without any binding.

I could assign the TableView a data source when it loads & it works,

However, upon updating new Entries, the TableView does not reload.

I saw the MonoMac Examples that uses TableView Binding, but I would not like to take that path.

How could I get TableView to update its list?

EDIT: The real question is that Could I get this done without using a Controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,

```cs
    tableView.ReloadData();
```